# how could I pass my stdClass into an array?

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, stdclass

I've got an stdClass coming from my database :

```
$query = $this->db->get('news');

if(isset($options['id']) || $options['limit'] == 1)
    return $query->row(0);
```

And I would like to pass it to my variable :

```
$data['news'] = $this->front_model->getNews($spec);
```

so that I can get to any property simply by doing `$data['news']->id`

but I get this message error:

> Message: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

why?

Comment: What is `$this->db`? Are you using a framework like CodeIgniter?

Comment: What your `getNews` returns ? `var_dump($data['news'])` and check what you've got.

Comment: If you are using CodeIgniter then you can use `return $query->row_array(0)` but I don't really think that is what is causing the error message.

Comment: Yes I'm using code Igniter, I know I cans use $query->row_array(0) but i would like to keep it as an stdclass, and put it into my $data variable that I pass to the view.

Comment: @ghbarratt My var_dump show me what'im lookig for, in fact, it is working, but I still have that error at the top of the page. When I mean it works, I mean I can access $data['news']->id anyway

Comment: Perhaps the error is actually occurring in the view? A stdClass can be fairly easily cast into an array but I thought you could use stdClass just as easily as an array in the view. Can you show us your view code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
return $query->row(0);
```

Use this

```
return $query->row_array(0);
```

It will already fetch the result in array form

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html

first remove the 0 from $query->row() because it only fetches single record. then print_r($data) to see what is coming

Also do this

```
$news = $this->front_model->getNews($spec);
```

instead of

```
$data['news'] = $this->front_model->getNews($spec);
```

Now you are able to call it like this

```
echo $news->id;
```

Comment: yeah but the thing is I'm looking to use it as an stdClass so that I can access my variable this way : $news->id instead of $news['id']

Comment: okay, but how do I pass it into the view then ? Because I'm passing an array : $data , and nothing else.
"first remove the 0 from $query->row() because it only fetches single record" => that was intentional ;)